# Making a radial gradient visual range

Tags: textures, javascript

[image]I am currently working on a project in p5JS.
So lets say i've got a texture and top of it, i've got a radial gradient that is overlapping on the texture. I want to make this like a cool vision range effect in 2D. I believe you can imagine this stitation.
So how am i able to start this thing?
Should i use another framework to do this?

Comment: "I've got a texture and top of it, I've got a radial gradient that is overlapping on the texture." - that sounds to me like a reasonably complete solution. Have you run into a specific difficulty implementing a radial gradient texture that's drawn over your game scene?

Comment: So let's say i draw a line on the screen, and there is a 'r' radius circle around my mouse position. with rgba(0,0,0,0) so this is transparent. and i want to fill the screen with black except the area what the circle covers. this is goal! And of course try to implement this with Javascript (p5JS)

Comment: Presumably you've tried doing this with [p5.js's gradient tools](https://p5js.org/examples/color-radial-gradient.html)? What code did you write so far, and how is the result differing from what you want?